# How to run a function in javaScript when all files have been Uploaded

Tags: primefaces

I am using a primefaces FileUpload's the sending of multiple files. I would like to know how to perform a function onComplete when all files have been transferred.
I am creating a p: dialog that runs at the beginning, and if I use the onComplete, after the first shipment, it already performs the function. I would run the function after all the items you were completed.
Anyone know?

Edit:
It could also, if I could spend the entire file that was inserted in the list, could control the event from the Bean. Anyone know how I can pass the full list of files included in the upload?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's not possible. Take a look at this, there's an patch to do what you need: https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3836

Comment: It could also, if I could spend the entire file that was inserted in the list, could control the event from the Bean. Anyone know how I can pass the full list of files included in the upload?